# Add "maximum"/"90 days" button to the "Recent Activity" page

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

On the "Recent Activity" page (`users/recent/[userid]`), it's possible to view the last 90 days of activity. For someone like me (and many, many others) who only infrequently visit, this is quite a useful list to be able to view, but the only way to currently view it is to manually enter the start date.

It would be nice to have a "last 90 days" button after the "last month" button.

Also, it would be nice to default to this view (or possibly to select the default). Currently, the default for this page is something like "today", where today is the whole of the date in question, even though part of that day may not have happened yet. That's totally useless for me, and is probably only useful for the select few who spend hours a day on these sites...

Comment: Ahh, feature creep...

Comment: Maybe. Then again, it'd be a hell of a lot more useful than the currently-existing "yesterday", "last week", and "last month" pre-sets.